# PostrgreSQL trying to perform a plsh function

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

**NOTE:** `plsh` is a PostgreSQL language that executes shell commands.

I'm trying to call a `plsh` function from within a `plpgsql` function.

First there's the bigger `plpgsql` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.big_function(my_arg character varying)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS backend.table_B;
    CREATE TABLE backend.table_B AS
    --Create a table with a SELECT with some joins,
    --right now the resulting table is empty

    RAISE NOTICE 'table_B created';

    PERFORM my_schema.insert_from_shell(my_arg);

    RETURN 'Function Ended';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Then there's the `plsh` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.insert_from_shell(my_arg character varying)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
#!/bin/sh
PGPASSWORD=mypassword psql -d mydatabase -h myhost -p myport -U myuser -c "INSERT INTO myschema.table_A(mycolumn) VALUES('$1')"
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plsh VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

When I try to execute the following:

```
SELECT my_schema.big_function('test');
```

it never ends. On the other hand, if I comment the `PERFORM` line from the first function, and call both functions separately, they each end in less than a second:

```
SELECT my_schema.big_function('test');
SELECT my_schema.insert_from_shell('test');
```

There might be a problem with executing `plsh` functions from within `plpgsql` functions, but I'm not sure.

I could work around it calling both functions separately using a script outside the database, but I'd rather solve it from within the database, and call a single function.

Any pointer or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT pid, relation::regclass, mode, granted FROM pg_locks;`? I bet `big_function` is run inside a transaction with statements that lock `table_a`.

Comment: I think you might be onto something. Digging a little deeper I found a trigger function linking `table_a` and `table_b`. Is there a way to commit the creation of the `table_a` mid-function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a trigger in the transaction of `big_function` puts a conflicting lock on `table_a`, as suggested in the comment, you could consider the following solution:

Make the trigger a `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` (it has to be an `AFTER` trigger then) and declare it as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`. Then it will not run right when the triggering statement does, but will be deferred to the `COMMIT` at the end of the transaction.

By that time, `insert_from_shell` has finished and committed, so there will be no deadlock.

Comment: Now I already left the office, but I'll try tomorrow and let you know! Thanks a lot!